# Removing has_many :through assocation via link

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-many-through

I'm trying to remove the association between an `Actor` and a `Movie`, associated through an `Appearance` model. I'd like to do this by clicking a link on the actor's edit page. I have found the method I need to use (`@actor.movies.delete()`), but I'm unsure where to put it and how to get the right `movie` id.

Below is my partial for the movie fields in the actor form:

```
<%= f.label :title %>
<%= f.text_field :title %>
<%= f.check_box :_destroy %>
<%= f.label :_destroy, "Remove Movie" %>
```

The above works if I add `:allow_destroy => true` to my `Actor` model, but what I want to do is rewrite it so it doesn't delete the movie, only the association.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I needed to do was, of course, delete the **Appearances** rather than the movie objects themselves.

```
<% @actor.appearances.each do |appearance| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= link_to appearance.movie.title, appearance.movie %>       
    <%= link_to 'Delete', appearance, :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method => :delete %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look here:
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html

> collection.delete(object, …)
>   Removes one or more objects from the collection by removing their
>   associations from the join table. This
>   does not destroy the objects.

Comment: As I said in my post, I already know what function to use, just not __how__ and __where__ to use it.